# Unable to retrieve multiple records in an Oracle extract

Tags: oracle

I need to get the year from a date in all of the records in an Oracle database. The following is my attempt:

```
CREATE or replace TYPE BODY student_t AS MEMBER FUNCTION getYear RETURN NUMBER IS
yearDOB NUMBER;
BEGIN
    SELECT EXTRACT(YEAR FROM s.dob) INTO yearDOB
    from student s;
    return yearDOB; 
END;END;/
```

But that will not work when the table has more than 1 record.

How I can fix the issue?

Comment: How exactly are you _calling_ that function?

Comment: if you like any date add `where ROWNUM < 2` , if there is a particular student add `where student_id  = <student_id>` . Otherwise you need collections or cursors.

Comment: "I need to get the year from a date in all of the records" You have now asked this question three times without explaining why you're writing a TYPE. `SELECT EXTRACT(YEAR FROM s.dob) from student s` jmeets your need. So why the TYPE? Obviously this is your homework but you still need a requirement.

Answer (score 0):

When you do `select into` rdbms thinks that only one value will be returned, or that your variable will be an array. You cannot set a NUMBER variable to an array of objects.